# Is there any way to make more than one announcement visible at once?

Tags: facebook-groups

Facebook groups changed the "pinned posts" for "announcements" where you can have more than one "announcement" that's what replaced "pinned posts", formerly you could only have one pinned post, but, even though you can have more than one announcement, only one is shown primarily and for seeing the rest you have to click en "show more". Is there any way to change this to make more than one announcement visible at once?